# How to Lock(Fix) one side of ui-slider in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Both the sliders are working.But i want to lock(fix) the left slider.

[image: slider image]

Initialized range in js:
`this.stopOver = {stopOverSliderRange: [0, 1439]};`

**This is my jade:**

```
.panel.style1.arrow-right 
  h4.panel-title a.collapsed(data-toggle='collapse', target='_self', href='#stopOverfilter') 
  Stop Over #stopOverfilter.panel-collapse.collapse.in .panel-content h6.booking-filters-title span#stopmin 
  {{listCtrl.stopOver.stopOverSliderRange[0]}}


min span#stopmax.pull-right {{listCtrl.stopOver.stopOverSliderRange[1]}} 
  min #slider.slider-color-gray
    (
    data-ui-slider='{range: true}', 
    data-min='0', data-max='1439', 
    data-step='60', 
    data-ng-model='listCtrl.stopOver.stopOverSliderRange', 
    data-ng-change='listCtrl.initiateFilters()'
    )
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask]. This question is about JavaScript/HTML/CSS, so you should consider using a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: Specifically, please define what you mean by "fix". In other words, you need to clearly state the desired behavior and exactly what it is doing that is the problem. In addition, please be sure that the code you provided is sufficient to actually duplicate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head>
    <title>jQuery UI : Birectionally Related Slider </title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/hot-sneaks/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
       <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#mySlider').slider({
                values: [25, 75],
                range: true,
                create: attachSlider,
                slide: attachSlider,
                stop: attachSlider
            })

            function attachSlider() {
                $('#lowerlimit').val($('#mySlider').slider("values", 0));
                $('#upperlimit').val($('#mySlider').slider("values", 1));
            }

            $('input').change(function(e) {
                var setIndex = (this.id == "upperlimit") ? 1 : 0;
                $('#mySlider').slider("values", setIndex, $(this).val())
            })


        });
    </script>


</head> 
<body>
 <div id="mySlider"></div> <br>
    <div class="inputs">
        <label for="lowerlimit">Lower Limit: </label><input id="lowerlimit" />
        <label for="upperlimit">Upper Limit: </label><input id="upperlimit" />
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```